# What's wrong with having the same variable in the integrand as in the limits?

Tags: notation

To give you a bit of context, if I'm trying to calculate the work done by a force from a distance $x_0$ (given constant) to $x$ (variable), I've been told (in lectures) to write the work done  as $$W=\int_{x_0}^x F(\xi)d\xi \tag{1},$$ rather than $$W=\int_{x_0}^xF(x)dx \tag{2},$$ the reason being that "we've got the same variable in two places".

But what exactly is wrong with this?

Is $(2)$ wrong?

Comment: Technically there is nothing "wrong" with it. However, it leads to confusion - as the $x$ in the integrand is not the same as the $x$ in the limit. It's best avoided

Comment: See : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109105/limit-of-integration-cant-be-the-same-as-variable-of-integration?rq=1

Comment: Technically there is MUCH which is wrong with it.

Comment: It's only mildly confusing here but it gets extremely confusing once you start doing multiple integrals. What does $\displaystyle \int_0^x \int_0^x x^3 x^4 \, dx \, dx$ mean, for example?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You point to the real issue. In principle $\int_0^x(\int_0^xx^3dx)x^4dx$ is unambiguous. But mathematicians like the abuse of notation that allows them to write what you just wrote and they find it worthwhile to sacrifice $\alpha$-equivalence to get it. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence .) I suspect that modern mathematics students with some computing experience may have slightly different ideas of what's reasonable.