# Derivative $d/dx$ of an integral will be $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we want to take the derivative $d/dx$ of, say, $\int_{0}^{1} x^2dx$, what will the answer be? does that mean to take $g(x) = \int_{0}^{1}x^2dx$ and find $g'(x)$? If so, we have $g(t) = \int_{0}^{1}t^2dx = t^2$ and therefore the derivative $d/dx$ of $\int_{0}^{1} x^2dx$ is $2x?$ 
 What needs to be done first, calculate the integral to get $g(x) = 1/3$ or do what I did and why? thanks

Comment: That integral is a numerical constant, not a function of $x$, so yes.  It's derivative is $0$.  This is true for any definite integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^2dx
$$
is just a number - it happens to be $1/3$. It does not depend on $x$ and its derivative (should you think of it as a constant function) is $0$.

I think you are confusing this definite integral with the indefinite integral

$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^2dt .
$$
The derivative of that function is $x^2$, which you know from the fundamental theorem of calculus even without guessing the antiderivative $x^3/3$.

**Edit** in response to a comment: see this answer about "dummy variables"
[What exactly is a 'dummy variable'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048884/what-exactly-is-a-dummy-variable/3048903#3048903) .

Comment: I know, If I wrote $g(t) = \int_{0}^{1} x^2dx$ it was OK for me, but what annoys me is when I write $g(x) = \int_{0}^{1}x^2dx$ why doesn't it make it $g(1) = \int_{0}^{1}1^2dx$?

Comment: The $x$ in the integral is just a **dummy variable** of integration (i.e. you could replace the integration variable with any symbol and it would be the same, e.g. $\int_0^1 x^2\, dx = \int_0^1 u^2\, du = \int_0^1 y^2\, dy = \int_0^1 \Upsilon^2\, d\Upsilon = \int_0^1 \ddot{\smile}^2\, d\ddot{\smile}=\cdots$). It is separate and different in meaning to the $x$ in your $g$ function (and it's nicer really here to use a different symbol for the $g$ input and the integration variable).

Answer (score 3):

- A *definite* integral like $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is a number; the *dummy variable* one uses does not affect the value of the definite integral:
  $$
  \int_0^1x^2\,dx=\int_0^1y^2\,dy=\int_0^1t^2\,dt=\cdots.
  $$
- Given any real constant $C$, one can define a constant function 
  $$
  g(x)=C\quad  \textrm{for all the real number $x$}. 
  $$
  The derivative of a constant function (at any point) is $0$.
- Writing $g(x)=\int_0^1x^2\,dx$ is bad; you are using the symbol $x$ for two different kinds of purposes: on the right hand side, it is a [dummy variable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html); on the left, it is used as a variable of the function $g$. If such expression makes sense at all, it means the same thing as $g(x)=\int_0^1u^2\,du$, which defines a *constant* function, the derivative (at any point) of which is $0$.
- The definite integral $\int_0^1x^2\,dx$ and $\int_0^1t^2\,dx$ are two different things: the value of the later depends on the value of $t$. In fact, 
  $$
  \int_0^1x^2\,dx=\frac13,\quad\int_0^1t^2\,dx=t^2.
  $$
- "Taking the derivative" and applying the differential operator $d/dx$ to a function are not quite the same. One can take the derivative of any differentiable function but one cannot applying the differential operator $d/dx$ to a function that does not have $x$ as its variable. For instance, it does not make sense to, say, take $d/dx$ to $g(t)=t^2$. But it make sense to write $g'(t)=2t$.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a major point of confusion here. The integral
$$ \frac{1}{3} = \int_0^1 x^2 dx$$
is a number. It's exactly equal to $1/3$. Taking the derivative of a constant is zero (since the constant function does not change).

Writing notation like
$$ g(x) = \int_0^1 x^2 dx$$
is very poor notation, since the $x$ appearing in the integral is not the same variable as appears in $g(x)$.