# Is my solution of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x (\arctan^2 x )dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, proof-verification

Is my solution correct?
If not, what is the right way to do this and where is my mistake?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x (\arctan^2 t )dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
(L`Hopital.)
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F'(x)-F'(0)}{2x\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(x)-\arctan^2(0)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}}$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
Thank you.

Comment: Shold it not be $$\int_{0}^{x}(\arctan(t))^2dt$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Isn't it the same as $$\int_0^x(\arctan^2(t))dt$$?

Comment: Your formula above isn't the same

Comment: It looks well in my opinion

Comment: ok, then see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109105/limit-of-integration-cant-be-the-same-as-variable-of-integration

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I understand now what you're talking about! I'll fix the post, thank you.

Comment: @fragileradius You need to justify that you can use L'Hôpital's rule, in particular that $\\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^ x (\arctan t)^2 dt = \infty$. Also, you don't need subtract $F'(0)$... the derivative of $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is equal to $f(x)$, regardless of $a$.