# Find $\frac d{dx} \int_2^{x^4} \tan(t^2) dt$

Tags: calculus

I've been stuck on trying to figure out how to solve this for quite some time and I haven't found the solution or method I need to figure this out. Please help!
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_2^{x^4}\tan(t^2)dt
$$

Comment: Are you sure you are taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and the integral with respect to $x$? Generally the integral is taken with respect to a dummy variable not related to the derivative.

Comment: The integral must be $$\int_{2}^{x^4}\tan(t^2)dt$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm honestly not sure at this point. I want to figure out how to solve this, because this is the actual equation presented before me, but I don't want to dissuade any helpers because of my lack of knowledge. So far I've tried graphing integral(2 -> x^4) tan t^2 dt to see if I could make any connection, but nothing so far.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @TomHimler it's not so rare to have the same variable as the upper limit and the variable w.r.t. you are integrating.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Wait, is that the answer I'm looking for, or am I supposed to do something more with this integral?

Comment: @Botond while it could potentially be done. It is much more confusing than just using two different variables. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109105/limit-of-integration-cant-be-the-same-as-variable-of-integration

Comment: You have to differentiate the integral with respect to $x$

Comment: @Botond Yes, yes it is (or, at least it ought to be). It's basically like saying $\sum_{k = 0}^ka_k$. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: You cannot have  both $x$ in the integral bounds (free variable) and in the integrand (dumb variable).

Comment: @Arthur It can make sense. It's up to you and your environment. I think it's a bit similar to writing $\int x \mathrm{d} x = \frac{x^2}{2}$, without the $+C$.

Answer (score 4):

When $F(x)=\int^x_0\ \tan\ t^2\ dt$, then $$ \frac{d}{dx}\ F =_{{\rm Fundamental \ Theorem\ of\ Calculus}} \tan\
x^2$$ so that $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_2^{x^4}\ \tan\ t^2\ dt
=\frac{d}{dx}\{F(x^4) +C\} =_{{\rm Chain\ Rule}} F'(x^4)(4x^3)=\tan\ x^8\cdot (4x^3)$$

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_2^{x^4}\tan(t^2)\,\mathrm dt$$
as the integral is usually done with respect to a "dummy variable"; reusing variables like that is bad practice.

In this case, using [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we get

$$4x^3\tan(x^8)$$

Comment: Thanks a ton, Maximilian! Huge help!

Answer (score 2):

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

---

Here $f(x,t)=\tan(t^2)$, $b(x)=x^4$ and $a(x)=2$

So $\frac d{dx} \int_2^{x^4} \tan(t^2) dt=\int_2^{x^4}0 dt +\tan(x^8) 4x^3-\tan(4)0= 4x^3\tan(x^8) $