# U "notation" in integrals

Tags: calculus, statistics

One of my textbooks lists the cumulative hazard function as H(t) = $\int_{0}^{t} h(u) \,du$.

Why are $u$ and $du$ used here instead of $t$ and $dt$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109105

Comment: You can use $T$ if you don't like $u$, $$H(t) = \int_0^T h(T)\, dT$$ or any other letter than $t$.

Comment: @azlif one of your t's is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $u$ may be to avoid confusing you, or for the purpose of making the following discussion clearer.  In $$\int_0^t h(u)\;du$$
it's clear that there are two unrelated variables, $t$ and $u$, with $t$ free and $u$ bound.

If it were written as $$\int_0^t h(t)\;dt$$ the meaning would be *exactly* the same, but now the two unrelated variables would have the same name, $t$.  This could be confusing. If the text discussed the variable $t$ the reader might think it was talking about the bound variable $t$ when it actually meant the free variable $t$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.